# Couchbase .NET Query Rows Are Null

Tags: .net-core, couchbase

I have the following c# function that selects all the documents out of a couchbase bucket.

```
public IEnumerable<CatalogueItem> GetAll()
{
  using (var bucket = _cluster.OpenBucket(_bucketName))
  {
    var request = new QueryRequest("SELECT `boxcatalogue`.* FROM `boxcatalogue` LIMIT 100;").UseStreaming(true);
    var query = bucket.Query<CatalogueItem>(request);
    return query.Rows;
  }
}
```

I can run the same query from the Couchbase console and it returns my documents correctly. But when calling from C# code `query.Rows` is null. When inspecting the `query` object in a breakpoint I can see it has a private member called Results which is populated with the results of the query, so why is `Rows` null?

Comment: Does it work when you don't `UseStreaming`? In the result object, is there any error/exception/message? Does `success` = true?

Comment: Doh - Removing UseStreaming works. Thanks so much.

Comment: `UseStreaming` should work though, and you'll want to use that for larger data sets, but I think you'll have to loop through results instead of using `query.Rows`

Comment: @MatthewGroves if Rows is null, how would I loop through? Results is a private member.

Comment: `foreach(var row in query.Rows) { }` - if that doesn't work, then there might be some other issue with streaming (maybe a bug, more likely a configuration issue)